# Circle gets cropped in windows phone 8 map

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I was trying to draw a circle in [Map Explorer](http://projects.developer.nokia.com/mapexplorer) sample ([direct downloadable link](http://projects.developer.nokia.com/mapexplorer/downloads/7)) from nokia for Windows phone 8 With `_accuracy = 200;` in file `MainPage.xaml.cs` at `line no. 592` and found that when we keep on zoom in at max zoom in then circle gets cropped. Can any one tell me what's wrong?
I think map tiles are rendered above the circle. Below is the screen shot

[image]

**P.S. I have filed a ticket also on [Nokia Developer site](http://projects.developer.nokia.com/mapexplorer/ticket/2)**