# How to get Dispatcher in non UI code windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I can get the `CoreDispatcher` object in windows 8 as

```
CoreDispatcher dispatcher = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
```

But how can I get the `Dispatcher` in windows phone 8
So that I can call

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
{
    //My statements
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher` to get the `Dispatcher` object in Windows Phone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found that you work in nokia. I have some issues with nokia map. Could you please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14929201/468724

Comment: Nothing I can actually do about this, but if you raised the issue in Nokia site, then I'm sure someone from the team will pick it up and take a look at it! :)